# Using a generic type argument in place of an argument of type System.Type. Is it a smell?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I often see (in many mocking libraries for example) methods where a generic type argument is used in place of an argument of type `System.Type`. I am specifically talking about cases where generic type is only being used in `typeof(T)` operation (i.e. no instance of type T is being used anywhere within the method, and T is not being used for either return type or other arguments).

For example consider following method:

```
public string GetTypeName(System.Type type) { return type.FullName; }
```

this method is often accompanied with a generic version:

```
public string GetTypeName<T>() { return GetTypeName(typeof(T)); }
```

**Questions** 
is it a bad practice or a good practice?
Is this a syntactic sugar or are there more to it?

I see this as misusing a language feature to abbreviate a call to a method that accepts an argument of type `System.Type`

Would you consider this a smell? Should this be avoided? or is this actually a good practice (to provide a generic method as a shortcut to avoid typing `typeof()`).

Here are some practical issues with using this pattern I can think of:

1. if an argument of non System.Type type is added - method *might* need to be rewritten (if order of arguments is semantically significant) to non generic version (otherwise some arguments will be generic type arguments, and some will be regular arguments).
2. it requires two methods (generic and non generic for cases where type is not known at compile time). Consequently adds unit tests which are mostly meaningless.

On the other hand this is a common practice (and majority is always right, right?) but more importantly ReSharper prefers that signature when I do Extract Method refactoring on a code that requires single argument of type System.Type known at compile time (and I learned to take their recommendations though not on faith, but seriously).

Comment: A zen koan basically - Is an argument of type type a type argument? And this irks me too.

Comment: the question is impossible to answer definitively. what smells to one may not smell to the other. the fact that the language supports both cases means that both forms are technically valid implementations.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to consider documentation. How obvious is it what the methods do? If you have two methods (one with `Type` and one with a type argument), users need to look at both and choose. People who aren't looking at your code may not realize that the second one simply calls the first.

Where it definitely makes sense to use both is when the type argument is actually used when it can be and there is some kind of fallback for the `Type` version. For example:

```
object GetThingOfType(Type type) { ... }

T GetThingOfType<T>() { return (T)GetThingOfType(typeof(T)); }
```

Another thing to consider: A type argument must always be written explicitly. If it is likely that there will be more than one operation to perform with the same type object, it's not helpful to use type arguments. Consider something like this:

```
var t = typeof(string);
var name = GetTypeName(t);
var assemblyName = t.Assembly.FullName;
```

Even though I know the type is `string`, I should not write `GetTypeName<string>` here because I would be repeating myself. By giving me an option that I would most often be better off not choosing, you're adding a bit of unnecessary complexity.

A more obscure point is IDE support of XML documentation. You document the type argument like this:

```
<typeparam name="T">important information</typeparam>
```

Then if you type `GetTypeName<` in C#, Visual Studio will show "T: important information". But, for some reason, when you type `GetTypeName(Of` in Visual Basic, it will not (as of 2012).

Answer (score 3):

You are right: consider the semantics of the method. Is it operating on *instances* of the type, or on the type itself?

If it is operating on instances, then it should be a generic method. If it is on the type, then make it an argument of type `Type`.

So in your example I would say

```
public string GetTypeName(System.Type type) { return type.FullName; }
```

Whereas

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

Is operating on the instance `source` of type `IEnumerable<TSource>`.

In general, I have seen generics abused more than well-used. Any generic method implementation that does a typeof(T) or worse still, uses any kind of reflection is not really generic in my opinion and is an abuse. After all, generic means it works the same regardless of the type argument, doesn't it?

So, in summary, I agree with you - it smells.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the `string GetName<T>() { return typeof(T).Name; }` pattern as it is a misuse (misuse is probably strong but I can't think of the right word) of the design pattern that is the reason for generics, namely: generic type parameters are there for the compiler and the JITter (see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410634/how-when-and-where-are-generic-methods-made-concrete)) so that they can generate the type specific storage, parameters, stack variables, etc etc.

Using it as a convenient method for passing a type argument at runtime to me smells. There are times when `typeof(T)` is necessary, but I've found them to be rare and usually needed only when doing complex things with generics, as opposed to simple type safety sorts of things. If I see it, I definately pause and ask myself why it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Methods that deal with types usually do just that: Dealing with types.

IMO, `Class.Method<SomeType>();` is much better than `Class.Method(typeof(SomeType));`

But that is a matter of opinion I guess.

Consider LINQ's `.OfType<T>()`, for example:

```
personlist.OfType<Employee>().Where(x => x.EmployeeStatus == "Active");
```

versus:

```
personlist.OfType(typeof(Employee)).Where(x => ((Employee)x).EmployeeStatus == "Active");
```

which one would you prefer?

Comment: Signature of `OfType` method is: `public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)` type argument is used in return type. You can not rewrite this method using typeof(Employee) without reducing result to `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: so your point is that this is a syntactic sugar and it makes code **much** better?

Comment: @THX-1138 Maybe it was a bad example, my intention was to demonstrate the syntax difference in both cases

Comment: but if C# would implicitly cast type exrpession (e.g. Employee) to an instance of a System.Type (i.e. would turn Employee to typeof(Employee) if instance of type System.Type is expected) - then you would prefer: Class.Method(SomeType) over Class.Method<SomeType>()? so it _is_ matter of having to type out `typeof(...)`. (I agree that this is a valid argument)

Comment: @THX-1138 probably, the presence of `typeof()` just makes it feel less natural. I guess the real beauty of C# lies in how natural it feels compared to most other languages.

Comment: If `OfType` used a `Type` parameter instead of a generic type, you'd need a cast in the `Where` expression. I added this cast to highlight an additional advantage of generic methods.

Comment: @280z28 excellent. Imagine if `Enumerable.Where()` and the like were not generic methods...

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said, it looks to me like a matter of personal preferences. From my experience, most of the methods accepting an argument of type *Type* can be syntactically "sweetened" using an accompanying extension method.

So, in case of your example, I would make the second method an extension. Using this approach, you get a solution for your second concern - no unnecessary unit tests are required. The first one, however, remains; but then, addition of arguments will require refactoring anyway, so it will provide an opportunity to change the consumers of the extension method so they use the modified version of the original one.

Of course, it's just a personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A generic method has an advantage over a method with a parameter of type `Type`, because it can reffer to other generic things using the provided type. This is particularly useful in the following scenario:

```
public string GetTypeName<T>()
{ 
    return Cache<T>.TypeName;
}

private static class Cache<T>
{
    public static readonly TypeName = GetTypeName(typeof(T));
}
```

This cache is easy, there is no need to mess around with dictionaries and it is automatically thread-safe.

This being said, if the implementation is not using this possibility, than the difference between the two is just cosmetic.