# At what point in time does an instance of a C# class with a generic Type parameter lose awareness of its "generic"-ness?

Tags: c#, generics, clr, bytecode, machine-code

I'm sure the answer is out there in ten forms already, but unfortunately, I don't know how else to form the question.

If I make a class with a generic `Type` parameter:

```
public class GenericClass<TTypeParam> where TTypeParam : class
{
     public TTypeParam InstanceOfTypeTTypeParam { get; set; }

     public override string ToString()
     {
          return (this.InstanceOfTypeTTypeParam == null) ? string.Empty : this.InstanceOfTypeTTypeParam.ToString();
     }
}
```

And then use it somewhere:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var instance = new GenericClass<string>();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(instance.ToString());
}
```

For the purpose of better understanding the mechanisms behind the .NET runtime, I am interested to know:

1. Does the compiler create a concrete, non-generic class `` GenericClass`string `` because it knows I instantiate one somewhere?
2. If not, does the runtime compile the `GenericClass<string>` into a "real" class when the process starts running?
3. If not, at what point in time does `GenericClass<string>` become something that a dumb CPU can understand?
4. If this happens at runtime, does the .NET runtime somehow "cache" the work it does to resolve this?
5. Is this a behavior that is configurable on a per-class or per-assembly or some other basis? Or is it not configurable? (IE could you ask it to do this work up-front if the default behavior is to do it when it needs to, or vice-versa?)

If it happens right before each call, I would think that this could incur some overhead and also that maybe it would be tough sometimes to predict the difficulty upfront of translating some high-level `.NET` instructions into real instructions.

I am also wondering as a follow-up whether if the compiler does a static analysis of all the permutations of the uses of generic types (if 1 is true), then if it also does the same thing with generic methods up front.

If you have the time I would appreciate if you could clue me into the correct terminology for these concepts (where ever I am lacking).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410634/how-when-and-where-are-generic-methods-made-concrete) should answer most of your questions.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thank you, that's almost perfect - except it does not answer whether it is possible to ask the compiler to do the work in advance. I mean, this is probably a real edge case, but it does seem at least theoretically possible - it could quietly package all of the possible permutations (excluding those from reflection) up front and then there would be no need for just in time compilation for this particular scenario... right?

Comment: You can't ask the compiler to create the concrete generic types "up-front". That's the work of the runtime (as currently implemented).

Comment: There is one way to do this, and that is NGENing your assembly, which will cause the IL code compile down into native code, where you'll see that concrete type.

Comment: I only thought, maybe it is, because the runtime seems to be able to cache previous compilations by generic class and parameter, so there is some mechanism for reusing it at run time,

Comment: The runtime is smart enough to see that if there was a previous JIT of a reference type generic parameter, it will use that jitted code for any reference type that comes along in the same AppDomain.

Comment: Andres explains things [here](http://www.artima.com/intv/generics2.html)